# Error when trying to add Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, installation, 64-bit, wcf

I'm trying to add Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation (and Non-HTTP Activation) to my Windows Vista Ultimate x64, but it doesn't work.

1. I go to the Control Panel
2. Select the *Turn Windows features on and off*
3. Expand the *Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0* node
4. Select *Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation*
5. Click OK.

When I do that, I get a progress bar that doesn't really do anything for 5 minutes. Then it slowly progresses to the right and sits there for another 5-10 minutes before giving up with this error:

> An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed.

The feature is not installed, but there's nothing in the Windows Event Log.

I really need this feature working, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed IIS recently? Rebooted since?

I've had a seemingly working IIS install block several other Vista/Server2008 component installs. I ended up uninstalling IIS and then doing a clean install of IIS + the other components in one go.

No way sure that's your issue, but can't hurt trying.

Comment: Uninstalled IIS, rebooted, attempted install again. Nothing seems to be working. FWIW, the WCF features are not part of IIS (not in the features tree at least)...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help to follow the steps from [Windows Server 2008 as development machine - step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327448/windows-server-2008-as-development-machine-step-by-step/327449#327449)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but .NET seems to be working fine. I tried out some of the troubleshooting steps and so, but to no avail.

Comment: All other google results are in the line of: Windows Update then .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (full package, around 231 MB), and then WCF activation should work